# What element can make the background:url(); to not display image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add the following effect in one of the divs of my website:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8DTzU0Iol8

I have done everything from the video, yet the background images of `.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg1` 2,3, and 4 don't show up even with full path and the jQuery doesn't work as well.

I am sure that the thing that causes these issues is that I've added the code from the tutorial in a div that's not directly in the body, it's in other div, that's in another div.

I will paste all the code of the page, both HTML and CSS and also link a code pen, because I do not know what part of the code is faulty...

This is a live codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/ZEYpzZy)

I've separated my website into 3 pages. I've added a parallax effect on the first page and I've tried adding the effect from the video tutorial into the second page.

I also have a `reset.css` file that's just too big to add here. I've found it online. Without the `reset.css` the codepen will have a margin at the top through which you can see the background image that should have been on `.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg1`.

What do you think ?

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', 'container_page_1 .column', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})

// eliminate scroll-bar
var child = document.getElementById('child-container');
child.style.right = child.clientWidth - child.offsetWidth + "px";
```

```css
/* *** index.html - START *** */

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#parent-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#child-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px; /* exact value is given through JavaScript */
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: both proximity;
}

header {    
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/V671cpsf/ps4-controller-min.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    top: 5%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header p {
    position: sticky;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.container_page_1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background-color: red; */
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container_page_1 .column {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container_page_1 .column:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.container_page_1 .column .content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.container_page_1 .column .content h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    font-size: 15em;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.container_page_1 .column .content .box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container_page_1 .column.active .content .box {
    opacity: 1;
}

.container_page_1 .column .content .box h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #262626;
}

.container_page_1 .column .content .box p {
    color: #262626;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.container_page_1 .column .bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg1 {
    background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/ZRYZ24Ss/ac-odyssey-min.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg2 {
    background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/x8h2XmbB/borderlands-3-min.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg3 {
    background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/1RjPCkYM/god-of-war-4-min.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container_page_1 .column.active .bg.bg4 {
    background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/qqzrBwg8/sw-jedi-fallen-order-min.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container_page_2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}

/* *** index.html - END *** */
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<div id="parent-container">
  <div id=child-container>
    <header>
      <a href="#page2">
        <h1 id="sticky-title">ACG - Gaming and e-Sports News</h1>
      </a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi debitis in libero tenetur suscipit iusto eum nulla dolorum aperiam adipisci unde veritatis vel iure, a nam, saepe exercitationem illum vitae.</p>
    </header>
    <div id="page2" class="container_page_1">
      <div class="column active">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>1</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>2</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>3</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>4</h1>
          <div class="box">
            <h2>What is lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg bg4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_page_2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're missing point in `container_page_1` should be `.container_page_1`

Comment: @dgknca I couldn't find the pissing point you are talking about. All my `container_page_1`  have a dot.

Comment: dgknca meant the JS code - you have ```$(document).on('mouseover', 'container_page_1 .column', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })```
and this should be ```$(document).on('mouseover', '.container_page_1 .column', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })```

Comment: Great. That fixed the JS code. The background images still don't show up though :(

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add any missing stuff.